# HTML/CSS sections not working properly

Tags: html, css

I have a simple HTML/CSS media site. It is broken up into a header, 2 sections, and a footer. It looks ok now, but in order for me to adjust top margin on second section I need to go at least `155px` before it will even move. Basically everything is around `155px` too high?  What is causing this? Even my footer needs at least `155px` top margin before it will even move. Can anyone see anything? I'm sure I am making a very stupid error.

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y7enrxxo/) of my issue, I've also posted the code below.

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
body {
 font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 max-width: 960px;
}
#wrapper {
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 position: absolute;
}
header {
 height: 95px;
 border-left: thin solid #000000;
 border-right: thin solid #000000;
 border-bottom: 4px solid #867E7E;
 border-top: thin solid #000000;
 background-color: #000000;
 width: 100%;
 opacity: 0.8;
 display: block;
 margin-bottom: 35px;
}
.top-nav {
 float: right;
 margin-right: 10%;
 margin-top: 40px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 display: inline;
 padding-right: 2px;
}
.top-nav ul li {
 display: inline;
 margin-left: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 margin-right: 0px;
 margin-top: 0px;
 float: left;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.top-nav ul li a {
 color: #FFFFFF;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: inline;
}
.top-nav li a:link        , top-nav li a:visited {
 padding-top: 5px;
 padding-right: 5px;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
 padding-left: 5px;
 display: inline;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.top-nav li a:hover      , top-nav li a:active      ,top-nav li a:focus {
 color: #867E7E;
 display: inline;
}
.top-nav a.selected {
 color: #867E7E;
}
.social-media-top {
 display: inline;
 float: right;
 margin-right: 41px;
 margin-top: 51px;
}

.social-icon {
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 margin-right: 5px;
 margin-left: 5px;
}

#music-content {
 list-style-type: none;
 display: block;
}
#music-content h2 {
 margin-left: 35px;
 border-bottom-style: solid;
 border-bottom-color: rgba(0,0,0,1.00);
 display: block;
}
#music-content li {
 text-align: left;
 display: block;
 width: 45%;
 float: left;
 padding-top: 15px;
}
#music-content a {
 text-decoration: none;
 display: block;
 float: left;
}
#music-content p {
 display: block;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.music-info {
 display: block;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 15px;
}
#movie-content {
 list-style-type: none;
 display: block;
}
#movie-content h2 {
 margin-left: 35px;
 border-bottom-style: solid;
 border-bottom-color: rgba(0,0,0,1.00);
 display: block;
 clear: both;
}
#movie-content li {
 text-align: left;
 display: block;
 width: 45%;
 float: left;
 padding-top: 15px;
}
#movie-content a {
 text-decoration: none;
 display: block;
 float: left;
}
#movie-content p {
 display: block;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.movie-info {
 display: block;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 15px;
}

img {
 max-width: 100%;
}



footer {
 height: 55px;
 background-color: #E8EBEF;
 color: #000000;
 clear: both;
 text-align: center;
 border-top: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
 float: none;
}
.bottom-nav {
 float: left;
 padding-left: 0px;
 padding-right: 0px;
 clear: both;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-top: 20px;
}
.bottom-nav ul li {
 display: inline;
 float: left;
 text-decoration: none;
 margin-right: 3px;
 margin-left: 0px;
}
.bottom-nav ul li a {
 color: #000000;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.bottom-nav li a:link         , bottom-nav li a:visited {
 padding-top: 5px;
 padding-right: 5px;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
 padding-left: 5px;
 display: block;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.bottom-nav li a:hover       , bottom-nav li a:active       ,bottom-nav li a:focus {
 color: #867E7E;
}
.bottom-nav a.selected {
 color: #867E7E;
}

.copyright {
 width: 25%;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-top: 15px;
}
footer p {
 text-align: center;
}
.social-media-bottom {
 float: right;
 display: inline;
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-right: 41px;
}
#media-content {
 width: 100%;
 display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>


<title>Media Page - </title>

<link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


<body>
<div id="wrapper">
  <header>
       
    <div class="social-media-top">
     <a href="http://twitter.com"><img src="images/twitter_gray_48.png" alt="Twitter Logo" class="social-icon"></a>
        <a href="http://facebook.com"><img src="images/fb_white_1024.png" alt="Facebook Logo" class="social-icon"></a>
        <a href="mailto:tkmets5@yahoo.com">
         <img src="images/mail.ico" alt="mail" class="social-icon">
        </a>
    </div> 
    <nav class="top-nav">
      <ul>
            <li><a href="page_index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="media.html" class="selected">Media</a></li>
           <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
         </ul>
    </nav> 
   
  </header>
  
  

  <section id="music-content">
    <h2> Music Selections </h2>
     <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="images/fff_150x150.png">
                    <img src="images/fff_150x150.png" alt=""/>                    
                </a>
                 <div class="music-info">
                        <p>this is test text 1</p>
                        <p>sdkljfkdlsfj lsdkjflksdf</p>
                        <p>skdjfskdfj</p>
               </div>
          </li>
            <li>
                <a href="images/fff_150x150.png">
                    <img src="images/fff_150x150.png" alt=""/>                    
                </a>
                 <div class="music-info">
                        <p>this is test text 2</p>
                        <p>sdkljfkdlsfj lsdkjflksdf</p>
                        <p>skdjfskdfj</p>
               </div>
            </li> 
             <li>
                <a href="images/fff_150x150.png">
                    <img src="images/fff_150x150.png" alt=""/>                    
                </a>
                 <div class="music-info">
                        <p>this is test text 3</p>
                        <p>sdkljfkdlsfj lsdkjflksdf</p>
                        <p>skdjfskdfj</p>
               </div>
            </li> 
             <li>
                <a href="images/fff_150x150.png">
                    <img src="images/fff_150x150.png" alt=""/>                    
                </a>
                 <div class="music-info">
                        <p>this is test text 4</p>
                        <p>sdkljfkdlsfj lsdkjflksdf</p>
                        <p>skdjfskdfj</p>
               </div>
            </li>                      
       </ul>
  </section>
  
  <section id="movie-content">
    <h2> Movie Selections </h2>
     <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="images/fff_150x150.png">
                    <img src="images/fff_150x150.png" alt=""/>                    
                </a>
                 <div class="movie-info">
                        <p>this is test text 1</p>
                        <p>sdkljfkdlsfj lsdkjflksdf</p>
                        <p>skdjfskdfj</p>
               </div>
          </li>
            <li>
                <a href="images/fff_150x150.png">
                    <img src="images/fff_150x150.png" alt=""/>                    
                </a>
                 <div class="movie-info">
                        <p>this is test text 2</p>
                        <p>sdkljfkdlsfj lsdkjflksdf</p>
                        <p>skdjfskdfj</p>
               </div>
            </li> 
             <li>
                <a href="images/fff_150x150.png">
                    <img src="images/fff_150x150.png" alt=""/>                    
                </a>
                 <div class="movie-info">
                        <p>this is test text 3</p>
                        <p>sdkljfkdlsfj lsdkjflksdf</p>
                        <p>skdjfskdfj</p>
               </div>
            </li> 
             <li>
                <a href="images/fff_150x150.png">
                    <img src="images/fff_150x150.png" alt=""/>                    
                </a>
                 <div class="movie-info">
                        <p>this is test text 4</p>
                        <p>sdkljfkdlsfj lsdkjflksdf</p>
                        <p>skdjfskdfj</p>
               </div>
            </li>                      
       </ul>
  </section>
 
 
  
  <footer>
   <nav class="bottom-nav">
      <ul>
            <li><a href="page_index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="media.html" class="selected">Media</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
         </ul>
    </nav> 
   <div class="social-media-bottom">
     <a href="http://twitter.com"><img src="images/twitter_blue_48.png" alt="Twitter Logo" class="social-icon"></a>
        <a href="http://facebook.com"><img src="images/fb_blue_1024.png" alt="Facebook Logo" class="social-icon"></a>
    </div>  
   <div class="copyright">
      <p>&copy; 2015</p>
    </div>
   
  </footer>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: I added the code from your JSFiddle to your post. Next time, please add the snippet yourself. You can do that by using the "Code snippet" button when you are asking your question (or if you like keyboard shortcuts: Ctrl + M)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear the floats of your `li`'s. I have updated your Fiddle by adding a clearfix style to your `section`'s.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y7enrxxo/1/)

The style updates were:

```
#music-content:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

and

```
#movie-content:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

When you float and element you take it out of the "flow" of the document. Meaning that it's parent container (your `section`'s) were not receiving the height of your floated `li`'s (which happened to be around 155px). They were only getting height from the `<h2>` headers.